# how do I pass values using jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a page with a pie chart (canvas 2d) which uses js function to create.
With the function, I can then in html input some values to draw the pie chart.
It simply looks like this in codes

```
  <script id="chart">
     piechart("piechart1", ["cyan", "yellow", "green"], [ 75, 75, 75]);
  </script>
```

Which means I can input fixed colors/angles for my chart.
What I'm trying to do is trying to make a few text input area so I can input numbers and either the script can automatically change to the number being input or using a submit button.

This is all I have at the moment can someone give me a hand with this?

```
<canvas id="piechart1"></canvas>

  <script id="chart">
     piechart("piechart1", ["cyan", "yellow", "green"], [ 75, 75, 75]);
  </script>

      <form action="" method="post">

        <label>Angle 1</label>
        <label>Angle 2</label>
        <label>Angle 3</label>
        <br>
        <input name="" id="angle1" value="" type="number">
        <input name="" id="angle2" value="" type="number">
        <input name="" id="angle3" value="" type="number">

        <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="submit">
      </form>
```

So let's say if I input 100 into the first text area and click submit then my

`piechart("..........[ 75, 75, 75]);` would change to

`piechart("..........[ 100, 75, 75]);`
or

`piechart("..........[ 100, 0, 0]);`since I didn't input anything into the 2nd and 3rd text area

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create variable then using that store your array and pass that into your function

Comment: @SridharR - ah! I get what you mean but how do I do it with javascript/jquery? I'm used to php but if I'm not using php I know how to store it into a new variable but pass it into the function I'm pretty much stuck here :(

Comment: see answer that way you can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really passing values. It's just calling a function when you press a button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // we don't want to submit the form

        $('#piechart').each(function() { // only do this if the element is found
            // clear the canvas
            this.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
        });

        var angles = [
            $('#angle1').val() || 0,
            $('#angle2').val() || 0,
            $('#angle3').val() || 0
        ];

        piechart("piechart1", ["cyan", "yellow", "green"], angles);
    });
});
```

`val()` gets the value of the `input` element. We do `|| 0` to set it to `0` just in case the browser doesn't understand `type="number"` and sends us an empty string.

Comment: works really good but there's a little glitch, after submit it only overlaps the previous chart.  Each time it just overlaps and still can see the previous chart if the newer angle is smaller than the previous one :(

Comment: @user1850712 In that case you need to remove the previous chart! I don't know how you'd do that: it would almost certainly be in the `piechart` method.

Comment: ah! I get what you mean...I downloaded the piechart from other places I guess because the chart is drawing and redrawing again since there isn't a way to refresh thanks a lot for the help...but I'm not sure who to give the check marks to :( can I give multiple?

Comment: @user1850712 It occurred to me that the simple way to start over would simply be to clear the canvas. This isn't complicated to do: see the edit to my answer/

Comment: it's the same though..if I didn't understand wrong, the way you are clearing the canvas is setting it's height and width to 0 so actually it still exist but just kind of invisible since the size is 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Change code as required

```
<canvas id="piechart1"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$("#submitBtn").click(function() 
    {   
    var input1 = $("#angle1").val();
    if($("#angle1").val()=='') input1="";

    var input2 = $("#angle2").val();
    if($("#angle2").val()=='') input2="";

    var input3 = $("#angle3").val();
    if($("#angle3").val()=='') input3="";

    piechart("piechart1", ["cyan", "yellow", "green"], [input1, input2, input3]);

    });
});
</script>

      <form action="" method="post">

        <label>Angle 1</label>
        <label>Angle 2</label>
        <label>Angle 3</label>
        <br>
        <input name="" id="angle1" value="" type="number">
        <input name="" id="angle2" value="" type="number">
        <input name="" id="angle3" value="" type="number">

        <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="submit">
      </form>
```

Comment: somehow with yours, after submitting the chart will show only a micro second which when I release the submit then it bounces back to default value again :(

Comment: try <input type="button" id="submitBtn" value="submit">

Comment: oh that's good!
but ran into the same problem as lonesomeday's I guess it's the piechart's code that's causing the problem...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var angles = $('input[id^="angle"]').map(function () {
        return (this.value !== "") ? this.value : 0;
    }).get();
    console.log(angles);
    piechart("piechart1", ["cyan", "yellow", "green"], angles);
});
```

[**Tryout in Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/XKmdy/)

Comment: weird..I tried fiddle it looks all good to me but when I put the code in nothing happens :(

Comment: You need to call `get` on the result of `map`. Otherwise `map` returns a jQuery object, which looks like an array in Firebug but isn't one in reality. [jsFiddle showing this](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/XKmdy/1/).